# Slight Pinching when two differently bevel weighted edges intersect with bevel modifier

Tags: bevel

[image: The problem corner]

[image: How I would like the corner to look]

First picture is how it looks now, second picture is how I would like it to look like. I have come across this pinching issue where when two edges with different bevel weights intersect, the smaller bevel pinches the inner edges of the larger bevels corner. I have tried everything I can think of and I can't seem to fix the issue.

Comment: Hi :). Looks like a bug in Blender 3.2. Previous versions don't behave this way.

Comment: Darn, guess I will have to work around it for now, thanks for the reply! :)